# Find Second Derivative of Spherical Mean for Wave Equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

The first derivative of the spherical mean of wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is

$$U_r = \frac{r}{n\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta u(y,t)dy$$

How do we differentiate this to get the second derivative $U_{rr}$  with respect to radius?

*****Progress so far*****

I did a change of variable and now stuck on computing

$$\partial_r\int_{B(0,1)}\Delta u(rx,t)dx$$ I moved the derivative in to the integral and got $$\partial r\Delta u(rx,t)=\sum_{ij}x_i\frac{\partial^3u(rx,t)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j^2}$$ and this I now have the integrate, and I don't know how to integrate this

Comment: What is your background on the field? Have you tried any strategies to tackle the result? Sharing those, and any intuition or problem you may have while tackling the problem will help us give you more meaningful answers.

Comment: @NicolasAgote I've added what I tried so far

Comment: I got it, use integration by parts. IBP should be pde students' goto tool whenever stuck!

Comment: If you want you can answer your own question to both make sure you got it right and help others in the future. Good job!